# Repeat icon for X times

Tags: laravel

I would like to make sure to show icon stars in a loop. I have no code to show because I was trying a little but to no avail, but I briefly explain my intent.

- I know the user's vote number ranging from 1 to 5.

**I would like these stars to be repeated by icons in a cycle for the times that the vote corresponds.**

Thanks to those who will help me

Comment: The code you tried but didn't work would be code to show. There's no shame in code that doesn't work, no matter how bad you think it might be.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not the point, but it is that I have tried so many solutions that I have nothing to show at the moment :/

Answer (score 0):

Supposing `$vote` is a variable that has the user's vote number, you could do the following.

```xml
<div class="flex"> <!-- or whatever class gives it the 'display: flex' css property. -->
  @foreach (range(1,5) as $value)
    @if ($value <= $vote)
      <!-- icon of a filled star -->
    @else
      <!-- icon of an empty star -->
    @endif
  @endforeach
</div>
```

Comment: Assuming your example or mine just posted, how should I do to show a half star if the vote for example is 4.50?

Comment: Many different ways to go about that, but half stars are just the same basic logic with added cases. You could use `range(1,10)`, multiply the vote by a factor of 2, and use modulus operator (`%2`) to figure out which half of the star you're on. There are different ways. Research them and figure out which one is the best for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I solved it just like that:

```
@for($i=0; $i < 4; $i++)
<!-- content -->
@endfor
```